# Can't open audio device /dev/dsp: Device or resource busy

Tags: debian, audio, alsa, mplayer

I am install Debian Jessie Beta2 on my laptop, and I just compiled mplayer on it. however when i use mplayer command to play some videos, i can't get the sound, the error shows as below:

Can't open audio device /dev/dsp: Device or resource busy

I tried to google and found a solution with running this command:

```
sudo modprobe snd_pcm_oss
```

yes it works. However I don't like to use this command everytime i reboot. SO i checked Debian Wiki pages, and it said to add the following two modules to /etc/modules file:

```
snd_pcm_oss
snd_mixer_oss
```

however, when i reboot, it get the same error.

Is there anyone can help? thanks so much.

Comment: `/dev/dsp` is not an ALSA interface. How did you configure mplayer?

Comment: I only use ./configure as default to compile it. nothing else.

Comment: Then you also got an error message regarding ALSA. Are you using PulseAudio? Does mplayer's configuration find it?

Comment: You should have looked though `./configure --help`.  There's probably alsa and pulseaudio module options.

Comment: had the same error with xoscope. running as root helped...